# How to call Gruntfile tasks programmaticaly (via code)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

How can list and/or call Gruntfile tasks from my code ?

Thanks

Comment: You can run a single `grunt` task using `grunt <TASK>`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
var gruntfile = require('./Gruntfile.js')(grunt);


var tasks = grunt.task._tasks;
for (var task in tasks) {
  if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(task)) {
    console.log(tasks[task].name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
grunt.registerTask('task', 'TASK', function() {});
grunt.tasks(['task']);
```

If the task is in a `GruntFile.js` you'll want to do a `module.exports` on it.